# What does sprintf stand for?

Tags: php

I tried looking it up on google and wikipedia but couldn't find an answer...
Does anyone know what 'sprintf' or 'printf' stands for? Is it an abbreviation for something???

Thanks

Comment: Lots of their functions have weird names. You'd think they would be more organised.

Answer (score 36):

String PRINT Format(ed).

I.e. print to string using a given format.

Answer (score 30):

The various members of the `printf` family, derived from C where they first appeared (though they hark back to the olden days of BCPL's `writef` call along that particular lineage), include:

```
printf    - print formatted (to standard output).
fprintf   - file printf (to a file handle).
sprintf   - string printf (to a string).
snprintf  - sprintf with added overflow protection.
```

In addition, there are variants of those starting with `v` (as in `vsnprintf`) which can take variable arguments like `printf` itself.

By that I mean that they pass around a `varargs` argument rather than a series of arguments, allowing you to write your own `printf`-like function. I've used this before when developing logging libraries in the past.

Answer (score 3):

sprintf originates from C. Refer to e.g.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/

where it says:

> Writes into the array pointed by str a C string ...

thus: *s*(tring)printf(ormatted)

Comment: @hobodave - to be fair, he did add the cross-reference link. I've had cases here where I've spent a few minutes getting references to put in an answer and in that time someone else has posted a similar answer without any references. Both answers are good.