# Matlab Adjust in Vectorized Code

Tags: matlab, concatenation, vectorization

A few days ago I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18465028/) and got the following splendid solution:

```
fid = fopen('C:\Testes_veloc\test.txt', 'Wt');
fmt = sprintf('%s;%d;%%d;%d;%d;%%d;%%d;%%d;%%.4f \\n',str1,num1,0,2)
[a,b,c,d] = ndgrid(vect2,vect1,day,1:15);
out = sprintf(fmt, [d(:), c(:), b(:), a(:), reshape(permute(MD,[2,1,3,4]),[],1)]'); 
fprintf(fid, '%s', out);
```

The variables `str1`, `num1`, `day`, `vect1`, `vect2` and `MD` are inputs of this function:

- `str1` is a string 1x1
- `num1` is an integer 1x1
- `day` is a vector 10x1
- `vect1` is a vector 7x1
- `vect2` is a vector 180x1
- `MD` is a 4D matrix (7x180x10x15)

The objective was to have a text file as follows:

```
result.txt:
RED;12;7;0;2;1;4;7;0.0140
RED;12;7;0;2;2;9;7;0.1484
RED;12;7;0;2;3;7;4;0.1787
RED;12;7;0;2;4;2;6;0.7891
RED;12;7;0;2;5;9;6;0.1160
RED;12;7;0;2;6;9;1;0.9893
```

However, `str1` is not a 1x1 string; it's a vector of names (189000x1), that has the length of the text that I desire. In other words, instead of only 'RED', I have many different others strings. Is it possible to adjust this vectorized loop to this situation?

I tried this (add the `str1(:)` to the concatenation part), but unsuccessfully:

```
fmt = sprintf('%%s;%s;%d;%%d;%d;%d;%%d;%%d;%%d;%%.4f \\n',str1,num1,0,2)
out = sprintf(fmt, [str1 (:), d(:), c(:), b(:), a(:), reshape(permute(MD,[2,1,3,4]),[],1)]');
```

For example, `str(1,:) = 'RED'`; `str(2,:) = 'FHAW'`;  `str(3,:) = 'KI81'`; a cell like this.
It fails to concatenate the string to the numbers. Does anyone have solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a short example of `names`. The solution might not be faster than a loop.

Comment: No reason to be sorry, I just think that you might have the code snippets already, it would be more meaningful if you did the comparison directly as opposed to some generic counterexample that I might provide. Also, in the previous question Floris provided a timed solution. You could adapt that to your timing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sprintf (like fprintf) fills format fields using the arguments in the order they are provided. If you provide more arguments than the format calls for, these functions repeat the format with the additional functions:

```
sprintf('%s %i\n', 'a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3)

% returns

ans =

a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Using Matlab's cell unravelling technique, you can prepare your arguments first, then pass them to the sprintf:

```
tmp = {'a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3};
sprintf('%s %i\n', tmp{:})
```

You can get fancier by concatenating cell arrays:

```
tmp1 = {'a','b','c'};
tmp2 = [1 2 3];
tmp = [tmp1' num2cell(tmp2')]'
sprintf('%s %i\n', tmp{:})

% Returns

tmp = 

    'a'    'b'    'c'
    [1]    [2]    [3]


ans =

a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Note that the layout of **tmp** is transposed of the layout in the format. This is because Matlab reads the data in row-major order, so it will march down rows, then columns, to get the arguments for sprintf.

So, in your scenario, you need to create a large cell array with your arguments, then pass that to sprintf.

```
fid = fopen('C:\Testes_veloc\test.txt', 'Wt');
fmt = sprintf('%%s;%d;%%d;%d;%d;%%d;%%d;%%d;%%.4f \\n',num1,0,2)
[a,b,c,d] = ndgrid(vect2,vect1,day,1:15);
tmp = [str(:) num2cell([d(:) c(:) b(:) a(:) reshape(permute(MD,[2,1,3,4]),[],1)]'])]';
fprintf(fid, fmt, tmp{:});
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm unable to test it right now, but I will try ASAP.

Comment: I think there's a bracket missing, isnt it?

Comment: Removing the bracket that is alone in the code (the last of the `tmp` line), I got the following error: `Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.`

Comment: Ah - I see. I'll fix it in my answer.